# can wishes let you get 5x of a card?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So normally in tournaments you're restricted to a max of four identical cards per deck but can you, with [wishes](http://wiki.mtgsalvation.com/article/Tutor#Search_for_a_card_outside_the_game_.28Wishes.29), get, into your hand, a fifth Force of Will, or a second Yawgmoth's Will or something?

Comment: if you have 4 wishes and 3 of the card in your mainboard and 1 in your sideboard, it's as though you had seven

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In tournaments "outside the game" as stated on the wishes only consists of your sideboard. The maximum of 4 of one card rule extends to your sideboard. So your deck + sideboard can only have 4 of one card, so NO you can't have a 5th card this way in tournaments.

Comment: The errata said that wishes pull from your sideboard but I didn't know the maximum of four of one card rule extended to it. Thanks!

Comment: @neubert, There's no such *errata*. There is such a *rule*, though. *Certain cards refer to “a (card or cards) you own from outside the game.” In tournament play, a card “you own
from outside the game" is a card in that player’s sideboard* --Tournament Rules

Comment: And the deck construction rules of every official offline [formats](https://www.wizards.com/Magic/Magazine/Article.aspx?x=judge/resources/banned) allowing a sideboard includes the following: *With the exception of basic land cards, a player’s combined deck and sideboard may not contain more than four of any individual card, counted by its English card title equivalent.*

Comment: In a casual setting, where the wishes extend to your entire card collection, can you get a 5th copy of a card that way?

Comment: @GendoIkari Yes you can. The 4 card rule applies only to the construction of your deck. If somehow during gameplay you get a fifth card there is no rule preventing that.

Comment: @ikegami. I mispoke. It's in the Rulings section of http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=34400 . A ruling as of 10/1/2009

Comment: @neubert, Those rulings aren't always correct or up to date. My reference, the actual rules, is much stronger.

Comment: The document that mentions that: https://wpn.wizards.com/sites/wpn/files/attachements/mtg_mtr_18may18_en_0.pdf